# Deployment and Rollback Strategy with Windows Azure

Tags: deployment, azure

I'm hoping that Microsoft Azure offers services in the areas of application deployments and rollbacks.

Specifically, I'm interested in accomplishing the following using Azure:

- Deploy an application with zero downtime
- Rollback an application in the event that a deployment fails

Are these features / services baked into Azure?

So that you can feel my pain...Right now, my deployment strategy through Visual Studio is a File System deploy.  I need to plan downtime, and most times I still have users on the system who are losing data (and therefore complaining) and ignoring the warnings.  And based on the urgency of a  feature request and deployment, sometimes a bug sneaks in.  A user discovers that, and obviously we need an immediate rollback (which inadvertently requires another unplanned maintenance window).

If you've had positive "deployment with zero downtime" and "application rollback" experiences using Azure, please share.

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, these features are baked into Azure, specifically in the deploy to staging and production-staging VIP switch features.

In order to get zero downtime, you can deploy to your staging environment, test until you are satisfied, and then VIP switch the staging deployment into production.  If you leave your staging deployment around and running, you can VIP switch them back if you encounter any unexpected issues in production.

The negative with this, of course, is that the staging environment costs you money for as long as you keep it up.  You could always test live for some period, and when you were sure you didn't have any showstoppers just pull down the staging environment until the next deployment.

https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/cloud-services/how-to-manage-a-cloud-service/

Comment: How do you syncronize database changes with vip swap feature.